# next flow error. Unable to Intialize nextflow

Tags: nextflow

```
CAPSULE: Downloading dependency com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:pom:1.11.25
CAPSULE EXCEPTION: null while processing attribute Allow-Snapshots: false (for stack trace, run with -Dcapsule.log=verbose)
Unable to initialize nextflow environment.
```

This is the error I am getting in my Linux when I run the following code:

```
nextflow run /main.nf
```

Answer (score 0):

So there's some issue downloading a dependency. It's hard to say what the problem is exactly, but you could try getting a more detailed stack trace which might help identify the problem:

```
CAPSULE_RESET=1 nextflow -Dcapsule.log=verbose run main.nf
```

However, it might just be easier to avoid downloading the dependencies altogether. Instead, you can use an 'all' distribution available for every Nextflow release<sup>[1](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/getstarted.html#installation)</sup>. For example:

```
wget -O nextflow https://github.com/nextflow-io/nextflow/releases/download/v22.10.7/nextflow-22.10.7-all
```

Then make it executable:

```
chmod +x nextflow
```

And move it to somewhere in your $PATH:

```
mv nextflow ~/bin
```